# web3.eth.getBlockNumber returns { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound ] }

Tags: nodejs

0
down vote
favorite
I am using express and web3 while i get the blockNumber it returns  { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound ] }

my code is

```
var express = require('express');
 var app = express();

const Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();

web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

let Block =  web3.eth.getBlockNumber

console.log(Block);
res.send("It is me");
});
```

But i need the block number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps off-topic, as this is really a JS question...

> it returns { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound ] }

That's because the call is asynchronous, so it's returning a Javascript [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

See the [Web3 documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getblocknumber) for an example of how to make the call correctly:

```
web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
.then(console.log);
> 2744
```

Comment: In the code at question, there is not even a call. Just `let Block =  web3.eth.getBlockNumber`, which obviously returns an object containing a function.

Comment: @goodvibration - Good point - I missed that there were no parentheses. Either way, he's going to need to understand how promises work for any of the web3 async stuff :-)